# Using Visual Studio 2019 having issues compiling SASS

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

Forgive my inexperience, this is extremely new to me.

Basically trying to customise themes in Bootstrap 4 (4.4.1) using SASS and when following along a tutorial for reference, it appears to not do anything at all when compiling the scss into the main.css file where you should have all of the bootstrap package, which should have been compiled.

I am using Visual Studio 2019, rather than VS Code (which most of my searching, everyone seems to be using). I have the bootstrap source files included, but it is the SASS Compilation which is not providing anything into the compiled main.css.

I have been following the following : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ovw43Dkp44 for reference.

Comment: Did you add bootstrap by NPM to your project or did you just download and include it manually?

Comment: downloaded it & included manually @nito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeming as I got no answers, only down-votes (understandable as my first question was very vague as I was very new on the subject)...........I discovered that this is down to the way I am referencing my source bootstrap.scss file.

Basically I am referencing it with the web-path, this has the effect of adding an import statement to the newly produced .css file. If I change the reference to a file system path such as:

```
@import "../lib/bootstrap-4.4.1/scss/bootstrap";
```

it now functions as I had hoped and the produced .css file includes all of the desired definitions from bootstrap.scss.